# Как остановить цикл ForEach после нужного результата?

Tags: javascript, валидация, foreach

Бьюсь с валидацией.
У меня есть несколько чекбоксов один за одним. Если юзер нажимает хотя бы на один чекбокс - валидация этого блока прошла успешно, но таких блоков несколько. Кроме того, мне нужен список ID заполненных чекбоксов для формы отправки. Все блоки с чекбоксами проверяются после нажатия на одну кнопку.

Хочу сделать такую реализацию:

После нажатия кнопки чекбоксы разделяются на два массива: заполненные и пустые. И на каждый массив вешается слушатель. Если юзер сначала не нажал ни на один чекбокс (все чекбоксы  - в "пустых") и нажимает на один из пустых - этот элемент удаляется из "пустых" и пушится в "заполненные" - и все массивы опять попадают на проверку.

В ходе работы возникла проблема: мне нужно, чтобы после срабатывания события "change" удалился только чекбокс, на котором произошло событие. А у меня получается, что так как удаление находится внутри цикла, то эта функция рассматривает отловленный инпут не как целевой, а как условие (что условие соблюдено) - и удаляет все элементы из цикла с каждым проходом. Вот сабж заключается в том, как сказать ему "Горшочек - не вари!!!" Чтоб первый раз удалил - и все? Пробовал заменить на цикл "For Of" но не получилось.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let emptyInputs = [];
  let tempInputs = [];
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  
  emptyChecker = (e) => {
      //for (i of emptyInputs) { 
      emptyInputs.forEach(function (e, i) {
        e.addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
          ev.stopPropagation();

          if (!e.checked) {
            
            i = null;
            throw e;
            
          } else {

            if (!tempInputs.includes(e)) {
                tempInputs.push(e);
                tempChecker(e);
            };

            emptyChecker(e);

            console.log(emptyInputs.length);

            emptyInputs.splice(i, 1);

            console.log('--- ' + (emptyInputs.length));

            return;

          } 
        })
      })
    }
    
    tempChecker = () => {
      tempInputs.forEach(function (e, i) {
        e.addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
          ev.stopPropagation();

          if (!e.checked) {
            
            i = null;
            throw e;
            
          } else {

            if (!emptyInputs.includes(e)) {
                emptyInputs.push(e);
                emptyChecker(e);
            };

            tempChecker(e);

            console.log(tempInputs.length);

            tempInputs.splice(i, 1);

            console.log('--- ' + (tempInputs.length));

            return;

          } 
        })
      })
    }
  inputs.forEach((el) => {
      if (!el.checked) {
        if (!emptyInputs.includes(el)) {
          emptyInputs.push(el);
          emptyChecker(el);
          console.log(emptyInputs.length);
        }
    
      } else {
    
        if (!tempInputs.includes(el)) {
          tempInputs.push(el);
          tempChecker(e);
        }
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="another01" id="another01"> Input 1
<input type="checkbox" name="another02" id="another02"> Input 2
<input type="checkbox" name="another03" id="another03"> Input 3

<button type="button" class="button">button</button>
```

Comment: forEach нельзя прервать. Вместо него используй обычный `for` и `break` внутри него

Comment: пробовал так - у меня не получилось, потому что обычный for работает только с одним элементом, а у меня их два: сам элемент и его индекс в массиве

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код, как именно пробовал. в `for` ты вполне себе бежишь по индексам, и получить по индексу элемент - тривиально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем так сложно? Массивы какие-то...

По нажатию кнопки проверки вам нужно выяснить, есть ли в каждом из блоков хотя бы один выбранный чекбокс. Если тут все в порядке, собрать выбранные чекбоксы отдельно.

Что-то типа такого:

**UPD:** добавил `Alarm`

```js
let ids; // тут будет финальный список выбранных элементов

let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    input.parentNode.querySelector('.alarm').classList.remove('active');
  });
});

const check = document.querySelector('button');

check.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');
  let error = false;

  boxes.forEach(box => {
    if (!box.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length) {
      error = true;
      const alarm = box.querySelector('.alarm');
      alarm.classList.add('active');
    }
  });


  if (!error) {
    ids = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    console.log(ids);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button,
fieldset {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.alarm {
  display: none;
  color: #ddd;
  border: 3px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 100%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="alarm">Alarm!</div>
  <input id="form1item1" type="checkbox">lorem ipsum<br>
  <input id="form1item2" type="checkbox">dolor sit amet<br>
  <input id="form1item3" type="checkbox">consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <div class="alarm">Alarm!</div>
  <input id="form2item1" type="checkbox">sed do eiusmod tempor<br>
  <input id="form2item2" type="checkbox">incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua<br>
  <input id="form2item3" type="checkbox">ut enim ad minim veniam<br>
</fieldset>
<button>check</button>
```

Comment: Я думаю, что это мне бы подошло, только у меня вместо сообщения об ошибке ("Необходимо выбрать...") вначале каждого блока находится скрытый элемент типа "Alarm!". И когда пользователь начинает включать чекбоксы, мне бы хотелось, чтобы "Alarm" гасился. Поэтому-то я и делал массивы и вешал на них сразу опять проверку! Прошу прощения, что не учел это в вопросе

Comment: Я думаю, что если возвратиться к моему коду, просто вместо цикла ForEach можно поставить While , и условием завершения поставить нахождение включенного чекбокса. И после завершения уже удалять найденный элемент. Может так сработает?

Comment: @Игорь00073 добавил Аларм... Зачем вам тут цикл, если вы можете с помощью querySelector понять есть у вас включенные чекбоксы или нет?

Comment: Мне цикл нужен, чтобы динамически менять коллекцию включенных и пустых чекбоксов и отслеживать после каждого нажатия чекбокса. Мне пока сложно это все допетрить, но у вас отслеживание стоит только на одно нажатие чекбокса. Если опять на него нажать - ничего не происходит. У меня-то тоже так было, но я не доделал. Я обошел это удаление (в вопросе) тем, что удаляю старый массив и подменяю его обновленным. Возможно, что можно обойтись совсем без циклов, но я пока не понял как

Comment: Точнее, не цикл, а массивы нужны. А удалять из них я могу только при помощи циклов.

Comment: @Игорь00073 У вас требования меняются по ходу проекта. ))) Если есть аларм и ставишь чекбок, а потом его снимаешь, естественно аларм не появляется, т.к. нужно нажать на кнопку проверки. У вас явно сказанно в вопросе, что проверка после нажатия на кнопку. Или вам нужно, чтобы после каждого измененного инпута запускалась проверка? Как это должно работать объясните толком.
Собрать массивы выбранных чекбоксов и невыбранных можно двумя простыми действиями - `document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')` и `document.querySelectorAll('input:not(checked)')`. Необязательно для этого мутировать массивы.

Comment: Андрей, спасибо!
Глобально - да, проверка после каждого изменения. Но в вопросе я собственно хотел понять, как удалить целевой объект из просматриваемого циклом массива

Comment: То есть, Аларм должен реагировать на изменение длины коллекции заполненных инпутов в каждом блоке.  Если длина отлична от нуля - валидация пройдена, если нет - Аларм

Comment: Я решил засчитать ваш ответ как верный, поскольку свой вариант решения я во многом сделал опираясь на ваш код, и публиковать его в качестве альтернативного варианта не имеет смысла. Но все-же, если говорить об ответе на вопрос в названии, чтобы удалить целевой элемент из перебираемого массива, лучший вариант - это filter();